# Debouncing (fire function only once in few second) with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to implement tag search on user input, but input is fast and i don't want to fire DB call for every symbol user typed, so i was curios, is there a simple a good way to debounce api calls let's say - one time after 3 seconds delay?

For now i come up with this:

```
  let searchDelay
  async function handleTagSearch(e) {
    clearTimeout(searchDelay)

    tagSearchPhraseSet(e.target.value)

    searchDelay = setTimeout(async () => {
      if (e.target.value.length > 3) {
        let res = await fetch('api/tag_seatch/' + e.target.value)
        res = await res.json() 

        console.log(res)
      }
    }, 3000)
  }
```

But is it a right approach?

Comment: Looks like a viable solution. Does it work in your app? You might want to put the `searchDelay` number in a [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook variable so that it doesn't get overwritten between renders.

Comment: yes, but i need somehow to pass e.target.value to timeout function. I just don't like it ;(

Comment: You can put `value` in a new variable the first thing you do in `handleTagSearch` an use that instead: `const { value } = e.target;`

Comment: it undefined always when i pass it to timeout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution looks promising, if you make sure that the `searchDelay` number is persisted between renders with e.g. a `useRef` hook.

Another way of going about it is to use a `useEffect` hook that is run every time the input `value` changes. From the function given to `useEffect` you can return a function that clears the timeout of the previous time it was run.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (value.length < 3) {
        setResult(null);
        return;
      }

      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setResult(Math.random());
      }, 3000);

      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    },
    [value]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <div>{result}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Tholle example i understood that qoute "The function returned from the useEffect function will be invoked `every time it is run again`, and on unmount as you say" and came up with this solution:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export function TagsAdd() {
  const [searchTerm, searchTermSet] = useState('')
  const isFirstRun = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
   //skip first run on component mount
   if (isFirstRun.current) {
      isFirstRun.current = false
      return
   }

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      tagSearch(searchTerm)
    }, 2000) //2000 - timeout to execute this function if timeout will be not cleared

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout) //clear timeout (delete function execution)
  }, [searchTerm])

  // API call only one time in 2 seconds for the last value! Yeeeee
  async function tagSearch(value) {
    let res = await fetch('api/tag_seatch/' + value)
    res = await res.json()
    console.log(res)
  }

  //handle input change
  function handleInput(e) {
    searchTermSet(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
        <div>
          <input value={searchTerm} onChange={handleInput} />
        </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you need to consider is using `useCallback` for memoization, if you just write a plain function it will be re-instantiated on each re-render. IMO you should use lodash's debounce function instead of implementing your own. the result looks something like this:

```
const searchTags = useCallback(debounce(async evt => {
  const { value } = evt.target;
  if(value.length > 3){

    const response = await fetch('/api/tag_search', value);
    const result = await response.json();

    setTags(result) //or somewhere in your state
  }
}, 3000, { trailing: true, leading: false }));
```

Comment: are you sure that you can use useCallback for function that can change values?

Comment: there is no magic behind it, useCallback with just make sure you don't re-define the function on each re-render, the state can be kept on a useState hook and updated within the callback, it is a fairly common use case

Comment: i think useCallback is for optimisation heavy calculations. Look at this article, maybe you mistaken something: https://usehooks.com/useMemo/